# UIKeyboardAppearance in UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, ios7

With iOS7, we saw the introduction of [UIKeyboardAppearance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIKeyboardAppearance). Works great when applied to `UITextView`, but, as [Apple states](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html), the `UIWebView` does not conform to the `UITextInputTraits` protocol.

> Although the UIWebView class does not support the UITextInputTraits protocol directly, you can configure some keyboard attributes for text input elements. For example, you can include autocorrect and auto-capitalization attributes in the definition of an input element to specify the keyboard’s behaviors, as shown in the following example.

Has anyone figured out the magical HTML attribute to set for keyboard appearance yet? Or is there not one? Any workaround? (No private APIs, please)

Comment: Uhm, what? Keyboard appearance has been available since iOS2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom webview keyboard issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664984/custom-webview-keyboard-issues)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A very easy solution would be to add a `- (UIKeyboardAppearance) keyboardAppearance` method via category extension to `UIView`.  In this method you could simply return `UIKeyboardAppearanceDark`.  This works because the method would magically be added to the internal `UIWebView` view (`UIWebBrowserView`) which becomes the first responder when the user taps into a HTML form input field.  The main problem with this approach is that it will affect all UIView-derived views, which may not be desirable.

We can construct a more targeted solution which intercepts the first responder that is responsible for the keyboard and adds a `keyboardAppearance` method to it if one doesn't exist.  This will degrade gracefully if the internal implementation of `UIWebBrowserView` changes in the future to include a `keyboardAppearance` selector.

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@protocol TSPingPong <NSObject>
- (void) ts_pong: (id) sender;
@end

@interface NSObject (TSPingPong)
@end
@implementation NSObject (TSPingPong)
- (void) ts_ping: (id) sender
{
    if ( [sender respondsToSelector: @selector(ts_pong:)] )
    {
        [sender performSelector: @selector( ts_pong: ) withObject: self ];
    }
}
@end

@implementation TSViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIWebView* _webView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector(keyboardWillAppear:)
                                                 name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object: nil];

    NSString* html = @"<br><br><br><form action=''> " \
    "First name: <input type='text'><br> " \
    "Last name: <input type='text'><br>" \
    "<input type='submit' value='Submit'> " \
    "</form>";

    [_webView loadHTMLString: html
                     baseURL: nil];
}

- (void) keyboardWillAppear: (NSNotification*) n
{
    // the keyboard is about to appear!
    // play pingpong with the first responder so we can ensure it has a keyboardAppearance method:

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction: @selector( ts_ping:) // added via category extension
                                               to: nil                  // to: the first responder
                                             from: self                 // "sender"
                                         forEvent: nil];
}

- (void) ts_pong: (id) sender
{
    // sender is the first responder.  Happens to be undocumented "UIWebBrowserView" in this case.

    // if it doesn't have it's own keyboardAppearance method then let's add one:
    if ( ![sender respondsToSelector: @selector(keyboardAppearance)] )
    {
        Method m = class_getInstanceMethod( [self class], @selector( keyboardAppearanceTemplateMethod ) );

        IMP imp = method_getImplementation( m );

        const char* typeEncoding = method_getTypeEncoding( m );

        class_addMethod( [sender class], @selector(keyboardAppearance), imp, typeEncoding );
    }
}

- (UIKeyboardAppearance) keyboardAppearanceTemplateMethod
{
    return UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;
}

@end
```

Comment: Neat. Would dynamically adding a method to a private class be in violation of any Apple rules?

Comment: @marklar - I don't think it's called out explicitly in any rules.  But I could understand the argument that it toes the line.  I'd be surprised if there were any other solutions (although I'd love to see some!).  Note that a category extension would achieve the same effect w/out specifically targeting a private class.  But it has larger implications in the app.

Comment: I've attempted this before and did not work for me. The browser view does include a traits object, but somehow it didn't change the keyboard appearance.

Comment: @LeoNatan.  Not sure what you mean by "includes a traits object".  It may conform to the UITextInputTraits protocol - but all of the methods on that protocol are optional, and it seems it does not implement keyboardAppearance.

Comment: There is an [actual `UITextInputTraits` object](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UITextInputTraits.h) behind the scenes, and all the classes that conform to the protocol actually forward method calls to that object.

Comment: The keyboard implementation gets this object from its delegate and renders the keyboard accordingly. I overrode the methods on the object itself, and it would still not take on a web view.

Comment: Adding keyboardAppearance to the UIWebBrowserView is working for me and I'm happy to post the project.  I don't doubt your analysis but mine is that UIWebBrowserView isn't using UITextInputTraits as you describe - otherwise your attempt would have worked and mine wouldn't.?

Comment: I think maybe the keyboard implementation tests what methods the delegate (in this case the delegate view is the web browser view), so it could be using default keyboard appearance value if the delegate does not respond to `keyboardAppearance`.

Comment: BTW, a much easier way to add methods or modify the web browser view is to dynamically subclass it and ISA swizzle the internal view of the web view. :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51829/discussion-between-tomswift-and-leo-natan)

Comment: Hoping to bump this. As this works for the iOS 7 simulator. iOS 8 has a white done bar. As soon as I tab through it changes to my color choice. So using this method, how can I prevent that white color so it loads my color from the start?

Comment: So only can edit for 5 min.  Question posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664984/custom-webview-keyboard-issues

Comment: Hi All, sorry for reincarnating this thread after a long time, I want to change the keyboard type to UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad, I am trying the same ways as modifying the keyboard appearance but not able to achieve what is desired. Any help please??

Comment: I posted a method that works in iOS12 and won't get you rejected from the App Store, at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54969004/2603965